# How to integrate my activiti app (version 6) with Azure active directory endpoint v2.0 without using ADAL.js or MSAL.js

Tags: azure-active-directory, activiti

I have an Activiti app which needs to be integrated with the Azure Active directory for user sign in and authentication. The application is registered on the Azure AD and I have the following information:

1. tenant ID
2. CID
3. key

I am trying to follow the steps in the official documentation [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/v2-oauth2-implicit-grant-flow), using the implicit flow.

All the examples I could find for it make use of the msal.js library to authenticate users with Microsoft Azure Active Directory accounts. But i need to achieve this without using any libraries. How do I proceed with this?

How and where in the activiti-UI do i need to put in the code to hit the following URL given in the steps

[https://login.microsoftonline.com/{tenant}/oauth2/v2.0/authorize?client_id=6731de76-14a6-49ae-97bc-6eba6914391e&response_type=id_token&redirect_uri=http%3A%2F%2Flocalhost%2Fmyapp%2F&scope=openid&response_mode=fragment&state=12345&nonce=678910](https://login.microsoftonline.com/%7Btenant%7D/oauth2/v2.0/authorize?client_id=6731de76-14a6-49ae-97bc-6eba6914391e&response_type=id_token&redirect_uri=http%3A%2F%2Flocalhost%2Fmyapp%2F&scope=openid&response_mode=fragment&state=12345&nonce=678910)

Any examples on this would be of great help!!

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

For the [doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/v2-oauth2-implicit-grant-flow) you choose, it does not use a library.

To refer to this doc, your app is required to be registered in the v2 endpoint, like [Application Registration Portal](https://apps.dev.microsoft.com/) or app registration(preview) in Azure Portal. And you also need to enable Allow Implicit Flow for the Web client.

Send the sign-in request in your browser:

```
https://login.microsoftonline.com/{tenant-name}/oauth2/v2.0/authorize?
client_id=your application id
&response_type=id_token
&redirect_uri=your application redirect urls
&scope=openid
&response_mode=fragment
&state=12345
&nonce=678910
```

The response like this:
[image]
By this, you could get the id_token for the sign-in user. If you want to get the access_token, you need to replace `openid` in the scope with the resource url with the format(like microsoft graph: https://graph.microsoft.com/User.Read), and replace the `id_token` with `access_token` in the response_type.
The access_token response like this:
[image]

If you want to parse the token, you could use [jwt.io](https://jwt.io).